# X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only not working in Firefox 20

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

I have the following Content Security Policy defined:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'self'; report-uri /foo
```

If I change that to `X-Content-Security-Policy`, the policy gets enforced and the report is sent. However, when I set it to `Report-Only`, no policy warnings appear in the console and no report is sent.

I'm aware of the bug where they don't support `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval`, rather you have to use `options inline-script eval-script`, but I'm not using either on this page.

I don't know if this has much to do with it, but the header is being sent as `X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only`, but Firebug translates it to `x-content-security-policy-report-only` - simply changing the case.

Also, when supplying both an `X-Content-Security-Policy` and `X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` as follows:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; options inline-script; report-uri /csp-report.php
x-content-security-policy-report-only: default-src 'self'; report-uri /csp-report.php
```

The console has a WARN level message:

> Report-only CSP policy will be ignored because there are other
>    non-report-only CSP policies applied.

So it's seeing the header, and instead of processing it and reporting but enforcing the other, it's dropping it altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uggh - I'd seen the bug report before, but didn't read it carefully and thought it was the `unsafe-inline` or `unsafe-eval` problem. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687086 actually specifically talks about inline script not firing the policy because the script is allowed to run. Doing testing with other things which violate the policy (such as loading script from elsewhere) the report gets generated and sent.